# How to import other javascript module in PhantomJS or CasperJS

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to build a functional test using CasperJS.
*caseperjs* is run by a backend test suite using the following command:

```
PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=../client/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs  ../client/ext_modules/casperjs/bin/casperjs test ../client/test/functional/init.coffee
```

In *init.coffee* I want to import/include other module (file) which seats just next to it. How to do it?

The following doesn't works:

```
require("user")
```

All I want is to get a content from other file into init.coffee

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of 1.1, CasperJS relies on PhantomJS’ native [require()](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference#function-require):
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/0-DYnNn_6Bs

#### Injecting dependencies

While injecting additional modules, CasperJS looks for path relative to cur directory
(the place where we run a *casperjs* command)
We can inject dependency using `clientScripts` option. However the injected dependencies can't
use `require` "globally". They are injected immediately to every page loaded.

```
casper.options.clientScripts = ["path/relative/to/cur/dir"]
```

Also we can inject modules using commandline args:

```
casperjs test --includes=foo.js,bar.js path/to/the/test/file
```

#### Using require

To import user modules use:

```
require "./user-module.coffee"
```

Then in user modules you can also use require. Using require paths are resolved
relative to the current file (where require is called).
If in user module you want to import casper libs, then you need to **patch require**,
check: https://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_modules.html

Answer (score 11):

After trying a number of the other suggestions (each expected to work in the context of their corresponding environments), hit on this solution:

```
phantom.page.injectJs( 'script.js');
```

Comment: Should it fail silently if the file is not existing?

Comment: Soz, haven't tried that.  Expecting it not to fail silently.

Answer (score 2):

There's [a section about that](https://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_modules.html) in the docs

```
var require = patchRequire(global.require);
require('./user');
```

In your case you should use `global.require` since you're using CoffeeScript.

Comment: Doc says that `patchRequire` is used *in order to allow requiring casper modules using their full name, eg. require('casper')* in user modules.

Comment: See the example after that. Maybe I misunderstood the docs, I didn't try it.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. thanks for this! I'm preparing an answer for this problem.